# How does AutoML Vision handle images with dimensions less than 224x224 pixels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-automl

I have trained AutoML Vision with 80x80x3 image samples. The training have finished successfully and I downloaded the edge tflite model. When implementing the tflite model in python, according this [tutorial by tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python) I realised that the tflite models input size is 224x224x3.

My question is:

- How does AutoML Vision handle images with dimensions less than 224x224 during training? Does AutoML Vision resize the images to 224x224 with interpolation?

For better prediction performance I would like to process the new images exactly the way AutoML Vision has processed the images during training.

When feeding 80x80 images with input shape (1, 80, 80, 3) to the model, I get the exception "Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch", see code below.

Feeding 224x224 images works without exceptions. However, I would like to use images with 80x80x3, like I used for training. Or preprocess the 80x80x3 images like they were during training in AutoML Vision, for example by resizing them to 224x224x3 or however AutoML Vision has handled it.

```
test_sample.shape

Out: (80, 80, 3)

test_sample = test_sample.reshape(1, 80, 80, 3)

Out: (1, 80, 80, 3)    

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors. 
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path) 
interpreter.allocate_tensors() 

# Get input and output tensors. 
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()

print(interpreter.get_input_details())

Out: [{'name': 'image', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 'quantization': (0.007874015718698502, 128)}]

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details() 

# Test model on input data. 
input_data = np.array(test_sample, dtype=np.uint8) 
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data) 

interpreter.invoke() 


Out: ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch 
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in set_tensor(self, tensor_index, value)
   173       ValueError: If the interpreter could not set the tensor.
   174     """
--> 175     self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
   176 
   177   def resize_tensor_input(self, input_index, tensor_size):

/home/cdsw/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py in SetTensor(self, i, value)
   134 
   135     def SetTensor(self, i, value):
--> 136         return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_SetTensor(self, i, value)
   137 
   138     def GetTensor(self, i):

ValueError: Cannot set tensor: Dimension mismatch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resizes the image for you. I observed this using netron to inspect the tflite and tensorflow models. Look for the input and follow the outputs past the decoder to the resize operation.

Comment: Maybe I should open a new question, but what if the input size is not square? I generated a tflite file from AutoML and the input size is 224x224. But my inputs are rectangular in shape. Thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this implementation

Set dtype

```
# check the type of the input tensor
floating_model = input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32
```

Resize your image according with the model height and width required

```
height = input_details[0]['shape'][1]
width = input_details[0]['shape'][2]
img = Image.open(args.image).resize((width, height))
```

Set input data

```
input_data = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
```

Here is the full example
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/python/label_image.py